# Make a reminder which will remind every X minute using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit, reminders

I am totally new in python GUI and Tkinter. Now i want an entry field where i can change the value or time of **self.hide** when i will execute this code. that means **self.hide** value will change from Entry field. In this code this value is statically set to 1 minute. need help from experts.

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import time
import tkMessageBox

class Window:
   def __init__(self):
      self.root = None
      self.hide = 1 #minutes
      self.show = 3 #seconds

   def close(self):
      self.root.destroy()
      return

   def new(self):
      self.root = Tk.Tk()
      self.root.overrideredirect(True)
      self.root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(self.root.winfo_screenwidth(), self.root.winfo_screenheight()))
      self.root.configure(bg='black')
    Tk.Label(self.root, text='Hello', fg='white', bg='black', font=('Helvetica', 30)).place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
    #tkMessageBox.showinfo("Notification", "Your time is up. Time to do next job. . .")
    Tk.Button(text = 'Close', command = self.close).pack()

      self.root.after(self.show*1000, self.pp)

   def pp(self):
       if self.root:
          self.root.destroy()
          time.sleep(self.hide*60)
          self.new()
          self.root.mainloop()
          return

Window().pp()
```

Comment: Try having a look at the "after" function of tkinter. It works like the sleep function but will not freeze your GUI.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method

Comment: i understand the code but i just want a Entry to dynamically change the time which  set up here statically(self.hide = 1)

Comment: I don't understand what it is you're asking for. Sorry. Can you reformulate the question?

Comment: This code generates reminder 1 minute consecutively. Here 1 minute is statically set inside the code(self.hide = 1). I want a Entry field where i will set that time through Entry field to execute this code consecutively.

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: In that case: use the after function and link the entry variable to the time.
Look at the link which I have posted. It will explain you how to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342757/tkinter-executing-functions-over-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This. It may help you.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time


root = Tk()

def close():
   root.destroy()

def show():
   root.deiconify()
   button.config(text = 'Close', command = close)
   root.after(1000, hide)

def hide():

   root.withdraw()
   time_to_sleep = set_time_to_sleep.get()
   time_to_sleep = float(time_to_sleep)
   #print time_to_sleep
   time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
   show()



set_time_to_sleep = Entry(root)
set_time_to_sleep.pack(side=LEFT)
button = Button(text = 'Set Time', command = hide)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

To summarise:

1. Instead of using the sleep function, use the after function. This will not freeze the GUI.
2. Set the "wait" time of the after function self.Entry.get(). This will collect the info you have put into the Entry.

For more info, look at these links. People smarter than myself give a very clear explication on how to use the functions.
[Tkinter, executing functions over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342757/tkinter-executing-functions-over-time)
[tkinter: how to use after method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method)

Comment: tired to do this thing. May not reach my goal.