# tkinter updating gui after mainloop()

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar, tk-toolkit, ttk

I understand that in tkinter once mainloop() has been run, no code after it will run until the window has been destroyed. I have found that the common solution is to use tk.after to call a function repeatedly at certain intervals. However I am using a for loop, and every time it loops it updates a variable which I want to see change in the GUI.

```
PB=myProgressBar()
for i in range (0, len(dataset)):
    performfunction
    PB.update(i)
PB.quit()
```

The aim is while performing an operation on each item in the dataset, the GUI will show how far the program is.

Within my progress bar class I have tried using a tk.IntVar as my ttk.ProgressBar value and setting the value through the PB.update(i) to update it.
I have also tried using ProgressBar['value']=i in my update method of the progress bar class.
In both cases if i run mainloop() before the loop, the for loop doesn't run (as you'd expect) but I'm not sure how to run mainloop and get update the GUI without a messy tk.after function that would probably have to involve a self.i value (and then do self.i+=1 at the end of the function that replaces the loop).
Is there a clean 'pythonic' way to do this?

Comment: Read [Event-driven programming - `.after`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759)

Comment: Sorry, `after()` is what it takes with `tkinter`.

Comment: You can run the code using thread.