# How to get value selected on tkinter scale (scale.get() returns zero)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, tkinter, tkinter-scale

I'm trying to create a GUI to run an experiment using tkinter. I need to assign the value selected by the user on a Scale widget to a variable called 'amount'.
However, scale.get() always assigns the value '0' to amount, regardless of where I am on the Scale.

Most answers about the Scale widget seem to suggest that scale.get() works perfectly for everyone else, so I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I'm using Python 3 and I wrote the following code to test just the get method:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")
slider = tk.Scale(orient='horizontal', label = 'Amount', length = 500, from_= 0, to = 1000, bg = 'white', fg = 'black', sliderlength = 20)

amount = slider.get()
slider.pack()
print (amount)
root.mainloop()
```

According to other answers, `amount` should be equal to whatever value I choose on `slider`. But the print command prints `0`.

[This is my code and the `slider`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RO2y.jpg)

[This is the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Usa0B.jpg)

> **Copy comment**:  I tried the following:
>
> ```
> def get_value(var): 
>     amount = var.get() 
>     return amount 
>
> var = tk.DoubleVar() 
> scale = tk.Scale( root, variable = var ) 
> scale.pack(anchor=CENTER) 
> print (get_value(var))
> ```

Comment: the `amount` you print is the initial value when you first created your `Scale` widget, which is 0. What you need is a function to retrieve the new value when executed.

Comment: @HenryYik
could you elaborate on how I can do that?
I tried the following:
`def get_value(var):
    amount = var.get()
    return amount

var = tk.DoubleVar()
scale = tk.Scale( root, variable = var )
scale.pack(anchor=CENTER)
print (get_value(var))`

Comment: @aasthas: `Tkinter` uses the concept of **event-driven programming**,
in which custom-written `callback` functions,
receive the flow of control from the `.mainloop()` dispatcher.
First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

You can link a command to your scale and get rid of the `amount = slider.get()` and the `print(amount)`.
This is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_value(v):
    print(v)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")
slider = tk.Scale(orient='horizontal', label = 'Amount', length = 500, from_= 0, to = 1000, bg = 'white', fg = 'black', sliderlength = 20, command=get_value)
slider.pack()

root.mainloop()
```