# how to run program in first frame after open another frame?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I created a gui program using python and tkinter. The first time I run this program, `self.start_thread()` is running well but after I open another frame and back again to first frame, `self.start_thread()` can't run again. How do I solve this problem?

```py
class HomePage():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('800x480')
        self.master.title("welcome")
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.master)
        #listbox.insert(1, self._var)
        self.listbox.pack()

        label = Label(self.master, text="HomePage")
        label.pack()
        button3 = Button(self.master, text="Page One",
                            command=self.pindah_ke_halaman_lain)
        button3.pack()






        self.start_thread()



    def start_thread(self):
        t=threading.Thread(target=self.hitung)
        t.start()

    def pindah_ke_halaman_lain(self):
        global stop_threads_1
        stop_threads_1 = True
        root = Toplevel(self.master)
        PageOne(root)

    def hitung(self):
        global stop_threads_1
        i=0
        while(True):
            print("saya "+ str(i))
            i+=1
            if(stop_threads_1== True):
                break



class PageOne():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('800x480')
        self.master.title("enroll")
        btn_back = Button(self.master, text="HomePage",
                            command=lambda:self.pindah_to_Homepage()).grid(row=33,column=1)



    def pindah_to_Homepage(self):
        self.master.destroy()
        #root2=Toplevel(self.master)
```

Comment: If you want to switch between frames, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter). You are using `self.master.destroy()` in **PageOne**, which destroys the main thread. Rather than doing this, destroy the **Toplevel widget - PageOne** to revert back to your main window (hide the main window when you switch to PageOne)

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759)

Comment: @FrainBr33z3 thanks for response, i was trying link which you share. but i still couldn't solve my problem about how to run again thread in homePage after i open and close PageOne. i use self.master.destroy() to close PageOne and HomePage be the only one frame/window was showing up. i am new in this field.

Comment: @stovfl thanks for suggestion. but i still have no idea how to solve my code. i need this  self.start_thread() will run again, after i close Pageone.

Comment: @YogiJanuardi *"i use self.master.destroy() to close PageOne"*: So stop the `Thread` also. If the `Thread` has only to run as long `PageOne` is visible, move the `Thread` to `class PageOne():`

Comment: @stovfl thank you so much. you save my time. thank you. it's solved. i use wait_window to ask if the PageOne has been closed yet?