# I need to update some Label Text from outside of the function that created it

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter.Label created inside a function and from a totally seperate part of my code I need to update the text.

I have tried just about every solution google provides over the last hour and I can't get any of them to work, some error, some show blanks, some just fail to do anything.

I am creating the labels as follows

```
def createWindow():
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    container = tkinter.Frame(window, padx=5, pady=5)
    summaryFrame = tkinter.Frame(container, bd=2, relief='groove')
    summaryFrame.pack(side='top', fill='x')
    summaryUser = tkinter.Label(summaryFrame, text='Some text').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
```

Much later I need to change the text of this label but because I'm no longer in this createWindow() function I don't have access to the summaryUser variable that contains the text.

I have tried summaryEvent["text"] (errors because it's not available), I have tried using a global variable and using textvariable=AGlobalVariable instead of text='Some text' (leaves the label text blank) and many other google results all with no success.

This seems like the sort of functionality that should be easier than this...

**EDIT 1**

I have tried the following...

```
summaryUserText = 'Some text'

def createWindow():
    global summaryUserText
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    container = tkinter.Frame(window, padx=5, pady=5)
    summaryFrame = tkinter.Frame(container, bd=2, relief='groove')
    summaryFrame.pack(side='top', fill='x')
    summaryUser = tkinter.Label(summaryFrame, textvariable=summaryUserText)
    summaryUser.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
```

When I try this the label just starts blank, not with the content of the variable.

**EDIT 2**

I have also tried the following...

```
summaryUserText= tkinter.StringVar()
summaryUserText.set('Some text')

def createWindow():
    ...
    summaryUser= tkinter.Label(summaryFrame, textvariable=summaryUserText)
```

But as soon as python sees the first line it errors with the following...

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 480, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 317, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'
```

**Edit 3**

The simplest code that simulates the issue in one complete file

```
import tkinter

def loadEvent():
    global summaryEventText
    summaryEventText.set('Updated')
    print('Updated')

def createWindow():
    global  summaryEventText
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    summaryEventText = tkinter.StringVar()
    summaryEventText.set('Init')
    summaryEventLabel = tkinter.Label(window, text='Event:').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
    summaryEvent = tkinter.Label(window, textvariable=summaryEventText).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')
    window.mainloop()

createWindow()
loadEvent()
```

No errors, the print('Updated') works but the summaryEventText.set('Updated') does nothing.

Comment: You either need to make `summaryUser` globally available (as a global variable or an instance variable, most likely) and call `summaryUser['text'] = 'new text'` later, or use the `textvariable=` option to refer to a `StringVar` that is globally available and call `.set('new text')` on that var later.

Comment: Have you tried returning a value?

Comment: *Only* the specific Tkinter "Var" types work for the `textvariable=` option, and of them, `StringVar` is the most likely choice for a Label.  So try `summaryUserText = StringVar(); summaryUserText.set('Some text')`.

Comment: I have tried that as well, but as soon as I use the summaryUserText = tkinter.StringVar() I get the following error... AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'

Comment: Looks like you're trying to create the `StringVar` before having called `Tk()` to initialize things.

Comment: @jasonharper The very first line in the file is "import tkinter, sqlite3"

Comment: @stovfl I made the changes you suggested and the error went away but it still won't update the label from another function.

Comment: @Jay2001: `window.mainloop()` is **blocking**, therefore you never reach `loadEvent()`. Your approach  turn the usage of `tkinter` upside down. Using `tkinter` the first line should `root = Tk()`, the very last line should `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: @stovfl it does reach loadEvent() though because the print('Updated') statement works just fine.

Comment: @stovfl Are you saying that you can't create the window (ie, run the root = Tk() and root.mainloop() statements) inside a function?

Comment: @Jay2001: You have to accept, that `.mainloop()` **is blocking**. First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759)

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is: to change an object you must have a reference to that object. That's not unique to tkinter, it's a fundamental aspect of programming. You're using local variables which by definition means you can't access the widgets outside of that function. The solution, then, is to not use local variables.

A proper solution requires you to save a reference that the other function can access, or provide a function that can return a reference. Have the function return a reference, use a global variable, or use a class variable.

The simplest solution for your specific example is to use a global variable. For example:

```
import tkinter

def loadEvent():
    ...
    summaryEventLabel.configure(text='Updated')
    ...

def createWindow():
    global  summaryEventLabel
    ...
    summaryEventLabel = tkinter.Label(window, text='Event:')
    summaryEventLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
    ...

createWindow()
loadEvent()
```

**However**, your specific example won't work because `window.mainloop()` will not return until the window is destroyed or you call its `quit` method. This means that `createWindow` won't return, so `loadEvent` will not be called.

If you were to structure your program to avoid this problem -- for example, calling `loadEvent` in response to a button click or some other event -- this solution would work.

Here's a working example that updates the label after 5 seconds:

```
import tkinter

def loadEvent():
    summaryEventLabel.configure(text='Updated')
    print('Updated')

def createWindow():
    global  summaryEventLabel
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    summaryEventText = tkinter.StringVar()
    summaryEventText.set('Init')
    summaryEventLabel = tkinter.Label(window, text='Event:')
    summaryEventLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
    summaryEvent = tkinter.Label(window, textvariable=summaryEventText).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')
    window.after(5000, loadEvent)
    window.mainloop()

createWindow()
```