# How can I make a Print and Clear button GUI which prints and clears a Label in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to solve a very small problem.
I want to make a GUI which has 2 buttons namely, Print and Clear.
I tried my best but cant solve it yet. Wanted Help....
Here is my code( ignore neatness ):

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()
main.geometry("200x200")
global buttonstate



def change():

    buttonstate = True
    return buttonstate


button1 = Button(main, text="Button", command=change)

if buttonstate==True:
   global label
   label = Label(main, text= "this works")

elif buttonstate==False:
    pass

button2 = Button(main, text="clear", command=lambda: label.pack_forget())

button1.pack()
button2.pack()
label.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

I am unable to do all the thing in a loop and also to print the statement when the button is clicked...
Thanks.

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the GUI with two buttons and a label,

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()

# label where you will print text
text_label = Label(main, width=20)
text_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, padx=8, pady=4)

# function to print text in label
def print_text():
    # the message you want to display
    your_text = "Some message.."
    # update the text of your label with your message
    text_label.config(text=your_text)

# function to clear text in label
def clear_text():
    # clear the label text by passing an empty string
    text_label.config(text='')

# print button
# command option is the function that you want to call when the button is pressed
print_btn = Button(main, text='Print', command=print_text, width=8)
print_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=8, pady=4)

# clear button
clear_btn = Button(main, text='Clear', command=clear_text, width=8)
clear_btn.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=8, pady=4)

main.mainloop()
```

**Output GUI**

> Click `Print` button to print message

[image: print button]

> Click `Clear` button to clear message

[image: clear button]

I have commented each segment of the code. Hope you understand