# How to wait for input in Entry widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a quiz in tkinter, and I have five questions. But, I want to wait for an answer to be inputted to the entry widget. I know I will probably need a button, but I don't know how I would go about doing that.
My code so far:

```
for i in range(5):
        randChoose = random.choice(choose)
        questionLabel = Label(top, text=full[randChoose]).grid(row=0, column=0)
        answerLabel = Label(top, text="Answer:").grid(row=1, column=0)
        answerEntry = Entry(top, borderwidth=5).grid(row=1,column=1)

        if answerEntry.get() == aFull[randChoose]:
            correctLabel = Label(top, text="Correct!",fg="green").grid(row=2,column=0)
            score += 1
            scoreLabel = Label(top, text=f"Your Score is {score}",fg="green").grid(row=2,column=1)
        else:
            wrongLabel = Label(top, text="Incorrect!",fg="red").grid(row=2,column=0)
            scoreLabel = Label(top, text=f"Your Score is {score}",fg="red").grid(row=2,column=1)
        choose.remove(randChoose)
```

Comment: you can check the input status by `root.update()` after button is pressed

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759). As it stands, you are stacking widgets over and over and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, add a button**

```py
button_pressed = StringVar()
```

this variable `button_pressed` will tell us if the button was pressed or not
(we set `button_pressed` to a `StringVar()` so `.set()` can change this variable, in the button's command)

```py
button = Button(app, text="Enter", command=lambda: button_pressed.set("button pressed"))
```

when the button is pressed it will set the variable `button_pressed`, to "button pressed"

```py
button.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

**Then, wait until the button is pressed**

```py
button.wait_variable(button_pressed)
```

this code will wait until the varialbe `button_pressed` is changed (to anything)

**Finally, check the entry**

`if answerEntry.get() == aFull[randChoose]:` etc.

**Final code should look something like this:**

```py
for i in range(5):
        randChoose = random.choice(choose)
        questionLabel = Label(app, text=full[randChoose]).grid(row=0, column=0)
        answerLabel = Label(app, text="Answer:").grid(row=1, column=0)
        answerEntry = Entry(app, borderwidth=5).grid(row=1,column=1)

        button_pressed = StringVar()
        button = Button(app, text="Enter", command=lambda: button_pressed.set("button pressed"))
        button.grid(row=1, column=1)

        button.wait_variable(button_pressed)

        if answerEntry.get() == aFull[randChoose]:
            correctLabel = Label(app, text="Correct!", fg="green").grid(row=2, column=0)
            score += 1
            scoreLabel = Label(app, text="Your Score is {score}", fg="green").grid(row=2, column=1)
        else:
            wrongLabel = Label(app, text="Incorrect!", fg="red").grid(row=2, column=0)
            scoreLabel = Label(app, text="Your Score is {score}", fg="red").grid(row=2, column=1)
        choose.remove(randChoose)
```

and you probobly want to destroy this button so on the next question it wont display 2 buttons

```py
button.destroy()
```

Comment: This is great thanks, but I get an error on answerButton.wait_variable(button_pressed), saying that button_pressed is not defined. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I had a spelling error, took me a long time to find. Thanks