# python tkinter waiting for an input to be inputted by user

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a code snippet. Entry widget creates itself with text, then waits seconds then destroys itself.

```
    entry_var_temporary = tk.StringVar()
    entry_var_temporary.set(varsoundTitle_usernameHeroContainer)
    entry_shtname_temp=tk.Entry(canvas2,width=30,textvariable=entry_var_temporary)
    entry_shtname_temp.pack()
    entry_shtname_temp.focus_set()
    root.update()
    time.sleep(10)
    entry_shtname_temp.destroy()
    root.update()
```

I have put 10 seconds to wait, and let user to modify the text, if it wants so. But as I see, time.sleep does not let the entry widget to be modified.
How can I get around this problem?
With `wait.window()` I realized I can edit text inside widget, but my problem is, it is not compulsory. So, if user doesn't put any text on it, it then after 10 sec needs to be destroyed

Comment: You've posted far too much code. If you're asking  how to have an entry widget only available for a few seconds, it shouldn't take more than a dozen or two lines of code to illustrate that.

Comment: The answe below is not waiting even seconds after creating entry widget. I am using 30 000

Comment: It's not waiting because you didn't tell it to wait. Neither `update` nor `after` will cause the code to pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an extension of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75346978/python-tkinter-wait-until-entry-box-widget-has-an-input-by-user-only-after-then) you asked. You only need to add one more line of code to that example in order to automatically delete the entry widget after 10 seconds.

In the following example, notice how I use `after` to destroy the window in 10 seconds. This call must be done before waiting for the window. This is the example I gave in your previous question, with just that one new statement added:

```
entry_var = tk.StringVar()
new_sheetname_entryBox=tk.Entry(canvas2,width=30, textvariable=entry_var)
new_sheetname_entryBox.pack()
new_sheetname_entryBox.bind("<Return>", lambda event: new_sheetname_entryBox.destroy())
new_sheetname_entryBox.focus_set()

# wait for the entry widget to be deleted, but automatically
# delete it after 10 seconds if the user doesn't respond.
root.after(10000, new_sheetname_entryBox.destroy)
new_sheetname_entryBox.wait_window()
```

Comment: I looked at it, I realized `wait_window()` method gives me possibility to edit widget. But I did not know how to bypass `bind` I did not want it to exist. Now the puzzle sums up after `after()` method is added upon the picture. Thanks!

Comment: Just Great!! thanks a lot! I guess I was also able to digest previous code snippets due to your explanation. Thanks @Bryan

Answer (score 1):

Use the `after` method with the `destroy` method as the callback.

The main reason to use `root.after` vs `time.sleep` is the `time.sleep` stops the thread causing the code to completely stop compared to `root.after` which is thread-safe because it is implemented in terms of call.

Your widget will destroy itself automatically after a set amount of time.

for example:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

entry_var_temporary = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root,  textvariable=entry_var_temporary)
entry.pack()
root.after(10000, entry.destroy)  # 10000 milliseconds
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: are you sure with `root.destroy` or it should be `entry.destroy`?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to destroy is what should be calling the destroy method.

Comment: I tried again, it did not fix the core issue. Being able to edit data in entry widget. When I click inside entry widget screen freezes, I meean tkinter window

Comment: @xlmaster did you remove the call to sleep?

Comment: Yes, I guess in your code there were not `root.update`

Comment: Sorry, but I need to edit the entry widget. Your code is not giving me that possibility

Comment: @xlmaster  Did you try running the code in my example?    If you do will see that there is no issue with using the entry widget.

Comment: main difference is that i put root.updat()` line after pack() and above `after`. Your code acts strangely, it does not stop running. Maybe I need to put also time.sleep() after `after()`?

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference, and it probably isn't necessary.  This would be easier to debug if you posted your full code or a [mre] @xlmaster

Comment: @xlmaster: as a general rule of thumb you should _never_ call `time.sleep` in the same thread as the GUI. It literally puts the entire program to sleep, including the ability for tkinter to redraw the window or react to events such as key and button presses.

Comment: Code runs only after it lets me to edit then destroys itslef

Comment: You see line print(Alelujah) so it show me the widget and prints that word exctly same even though I have put root,update above and below after methods. After code finsihes it let me edit the widget and I put 30000 milliseconds. Guess does not wait

Comment: Impossible with your code, I have even changed `root.after(30000,) ` to `entry.after()` it does not stop even a blink of eye moment, it continues running after. After the code has finished it then lets me to edit the widget

Comment: @xlmaster: using `after` won't pause the code. The code will continue to run. You must also call `wait_window` if you expect the code to wait until the widget is destroyed.

Comment: @xlmaster  in general you should put any long running code in a separate thread otherwise you will always have issues with frozen gui