# Destroy label in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use the destroy command to eliminate a Label, but the command remove only the last character of the text.
when I call the function to write data ("w") in the label, it works very good, but if I call the function to destroy it ("d"), just last character is removed. The function is below:

```
def escreve(texto, oper, pos_x, pos_y):
    global lb
    if oper == "w": 
        lb = Label(janela, text = texto, font = "arial 16")
        lb.grid(row = pos_x, column = pos_y, padx = 2, pady = 2)
    if oper == "d":
        lb.destroy()
```

Comment: people why the answer has been deleted? What I made wrong?

Comment: I can't find an example of `.destroy()` as a string-bound function, or a function on any generic variable outside of, say, [tkinter's .destroy()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destroy-method-in-tkinter-python/). Are you sure you don't want `del lb` instead?

Comment: I need to destroy the label, but I think that my fault is that I need to change only the text and not to use the Label complete to do this. I think that the Python is create the new one everytime

Comment: So if I'm guessing right, this function creates a Label class instance and, depending on the `oper` variable, it either modifies the grid variable or deletes the instance. Is that what you're after?

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759) it seems you are stacking `Label` widgets.