# Animating a GUI with Python (Dice Generator)

Tags: python, class, animation, tkinter, time

I am creating a simple Dice generator using BreezyPythonGUI. I got the whole thing to work, but now I am attempting to create a *rolling* or *flipping* animation before the dice *roll*. You will likely understand what I am attempting to do by reading under the *generate* function.

```
'''Dice rolling generator'''

import random
from breezypythongui import EasyFrame
import time
from tkinter import PhotoImage
#from tkinter.font import Font

class DiceGenerator(EasyFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        EasyFrame.__init__(self, "Dice Generator")
        self.setResizable(True)
        self.setBackground('#6D8DB9')
        self.addLabel(text = 'Dice Generator', row = 0,
                      column = 0, columnspan = 2, background = '#6D8DB9')
        self.die1 = self.addLabel(text = '-', row = 1,
                      column = 0, sticky = 'E',
                      foreground = '#FFFFFF', background = '#6D8DB9')
        self.die2 = self.addLabel(text = '-', row = 1,
                      column = 1, sticky = 'W',
                      foreground = '#FFFFFF', background = '#6D8DB9')
        self.image1 = PhotoImage(file = 'd6.png')
        self.image2 = PhotoImage(file = 'd6.png')
        self.die1["image"] = self.image1
        self.die2["image"] = self.image2

#        self.die1.configure(font = 14)
#        self.die2.configure(font = 14)
        self.generate = self.addButton(text = 'Go!', row = 2,
                                       column = 0, columnspan = 2,
                                       command = self.generate)
        self.generate.configure(width = 10)

    def generate(self):
        'This is where I am attempting the animation'

        for i in range(20):
            x1 = random.randint(1, 6)
            y1 = random.randint(1, 6)
            time.sleep(.1)
            self.image1.configure(file = 'd' + str(x1) + '.png')
            self.image2.configure(file = 'd' + str(y1) + '.png')

        'The final rolled dice correctly display after this following code.'
        x = random.randint(1, 6)
        y = random.randint(1, 6)

        self.image1.configure(file = 'd' + str(x) + '.png')
        self.image2.configure(file = 'd' + str(y) + '.png')


def main():
    DiceGenerator().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the `generate()` function, it pauses for the sleeping time times 20 (because of `range(20)`) and then displays the rolled dice. Instead of going through the animation it just acts like it is frozen.

What do I do to create this animation?

Comment: As in the for loop, tkinter mainloop does not take control to update the changes.  Add `self.update()` inside the end of for loop block to force the update.

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759)

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't call `time.sleep()` in tkinter applications. You should instead use the universal widget [`after()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method to schedule calls to a function that updates the images. There a numerous examples of doing that in related questions here about animation in tkinter if you look for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tkinter does not take control during the for loop, so the changes cannot be updated.  Add `self.update()` at the end of the for loop block to force the update:

```
for i in range(20):
    ...
    self.update()
```