# How to return an output directly without creating a button in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-menu

Good evening, I am struggling to return an output without creating a button in Tkinker. I want to return either "Excellent" or "Done" based on the input but only the input is showing.

Below is the code I'm struggling with

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

num = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=num).pack()

remark = StringVar()
entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=remark).pack()

def set_label(name, index, mode):
    return remark.set(num.get())
    if result > 56:
        return "Excellent"
    else:
        return "Done"

num.trace('w', set_label)
num.set('')

root.mainloop
```

Comment: `if result > 56:...` is not executed.

Comment: Return the output to whom or what? The `set_label()` function is going to be called by `tkinter` whenever `num` is changed, and it doesn't care what value is returned. I don't think you understand [event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342757/tkinter-executing-functions-over-time).

Comment: Also note that `pack()` always returns `None`, so that's the value you're assigning to `entry1` and `entry2`.

Comment: Everything was working with a button but I wanted to remove the button and that's where I got lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not exactly sure what you wanted to do, but I modified your function to determine if num entry is ''.  If not then convert value fetched to int and compare to 56.  If larger, then insert entry "Excellent" in remark entry, otherwise put "Done" in remark entry.

As you enter each digit, the comparison to 56 will take place so the first digit will always result in "Done" appearing.  Once you exceed 56 (which will require a minimum of 2 digits) it will continue to remain "Excellent".

Again, I did the best I could with the logic provided.  Here's the full code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

num = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=num).pack()

remark = StringVar()
entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=remark).pack()

def set_label(name, index, mode):
    result = num.get()
    if result == '':
        pass # not sure what rule should be here
    else:
        result = int(result)
        if result > 56:
            remark.set("Excellent")
        else:
            remark.set("Done")

num.trace('w', set_label)
num.set('')

root.mainloop
```

Comment: Your code is working exactly how I wanted. I now know what I was missing. Thank you very much

Comment: Great!  Please accept (up-arrow) the solution if you are satisfied that it works properly.  Thank you.