# Add entry widget according to value given in previous tkinter entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I added an entry wizard with label. How can I add another entry wizard if the value of the previous entry wizard satisfies the condition?

Here is my code

```py
def JoinHouses():
    Label(root, text="Input the feature to join").grid(row=1)
    e1 = Entry(root)
    e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    Button(root, text="submit", command=house(e1.get())).grid(row=2)

def house(a):
    HouseEntry = []   
    if a == "house":
        for i in range(3,7):
            HouseEntry.append(Label(root, text="Input the remarks to join").grid(row=i))
            e2 = Entry(root)
            e2.grid(row=i, column=1)
```

Comment: You can bind a event `<Key>` for the previous entry widget.

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759)