# Tkinter else clause is executing ahead of if statement upon button activation

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

```
def delFile(self, num):
    if os.path.exists("quiz"+str(num)+".txt"):
        os.remove("quiz"+str(num)+".txt")
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Removed!", "Quiz successfully Removed!")
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error!", "Quiz file not found!")

    if os.path.exists("answer"+(num)+".txt"):
        os.remove("answer"+(num)+".txt")
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Removed!", "Answers successfully Removed!")
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error!", "Answer file not found!")

delete = quizEdit("a")
root = Tk()
root.geometry("450x320")
root.title("Remove a text file")

label1 = Label(root, text = "What to remove?")
label1.place(x=70, y = 140)

entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.place(x = 180, y = 140)

et = entry1.get()

button1 = Button(root, text = "Remove", command=lambda : delete.delFile(et))
button1.place(x=210, y=200)


root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to make it so that the delFile method can delete a text file from the directory based on whatever is entered from the entry in the GUI. However when I press the button it just outputs the else clause messagebox.

delFile is a method of a class called quizEdit.

Comment: You are calling the `get()` method about a millisecond after you create the entry. The user won't have an opportunity to enter any data.

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759)

Comment: @BryanOakley Alright I fixed it by simply passing the get() method as the parameter instead of using a variable. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're calling `.get()` about a millisecond after creating the entry widget, well before the user even sees the entry widget.

As a rule of thumb, GUI functions need to request data at the point that they need it. In your case I would make a callback specifically designed to get the value and then call your function.

```
...
def do_delete():
    num = entry1.get()
    delete.delFile(num)
...
button1 = Button(root, text = "Remove", command=do_delete)
...
```

This isn't the only solution, but for me it's the cleanest. You could set the command to a `lambda` which calls `get()`, but I find that sort of pattern to be harder to understand and harder to debug. Another option would to be call `get()` inside `delFile`, but that tightly couples the UI to the `quizEdit` object which may or may not be desirable.