# Make python wait for setting of variable through tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, block, wait

Im running into this problem with tkinter, where I want to set the source of a document so my code can work with the file in python using a search button and askopenfilename.

here is the snipped of my code.

```
...
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.title("Alpha")
root.iconbitmap('images\alpha.ico')


def search():
    global location
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select A File",
                                               filetypes=(("txt files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    location = root.filename

open_button = Button(root, text="Open File", command=search).pack()


input_txt = open(location, "r", encoding="utf8")
...
root.mainloop()
```

Problem: As I am running the program, the window opens for a brief moment and I am instantly getting the error that `location` in the `input_txt` variable is not defined, which I totally understand. I guess my python code is not waiting for me to press the button in the program window and search for my file so `location` can be defined. How can I make python wait for `open()` to return a value for `location` before trying to define `input_txt`?

I have tried with

```
import time
...
location = ''
open_button = Button(root, text="Open File", command=open).pack()
while not location:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

this however causes the program to freeze and I know sleep is not the not the best option here.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't entirely get what you are trying to achieve here. I get that you want to open a file based on a GUI input from an user, but in your first code snippet I don't get why you define a global variable. You might as well do the manipulation of the input file inside your function.

Comment: I don't think you understand GUI event processing & programming. See @Bryan Oakley's answer to [Tkinter — executing functions over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342757/tkinter-executing-functions-over-time).

Answer (score 1):

### Regarding your question

Like boomkin suggests, I'd advise moving the `input_txt = open(location, ...)` line into your `search` function.  That way, the program will only try to open from `location` once you've pressed the button and defined `location`.

If there's other stuff going on, you could make another function and call that:

```
def file_handling(location):
    input_txt = open(location, "r", encoding="utf8")
    ... #anything using input_txt

def search():
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select A File",
                                               filetypes=(("txt files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    file_handling(root.filename)

open_button = Button(root, text="Open File", command=search)
open_button.pack()
...
root.mainloop()
```

The issue is that Tkinter objects don't do anything until you reach the mainloop--but once you're in the mainloop, you can't go back and fill anything in.  So everything you want to do has to be tied to some sort of input: like a button press (or a keystroke, or a mouseover).

In this case, you want to set `location`, but you have to wait until you call mainloop and the button starts taking input.  But by that time, you've passed the line that needs `location` and can't go back.  That's why I suggest calling the `input_txt` line from the `search` function--because it won't get called until you've already gotten the location.

That's a little long-winded, but I hope it illuminated the issue.

### As a sidenote

I'd also recommend you declare and pack your widgets separately.  That is, change this:

```
open_button = Button(root, text="Open File", command=search).pack()
```

to this:

```
open_button = Button(root, text="Open File", command=search)
open_button.pack()
```

Otherwise, you end up storing the value of `pack()` (which is `None`) instead of storing your widgets (the `Button` object).

Comment: Tkinter objects are not idle before the mainloop, mainloop is the infinite loop that gets them shown/drawn and stay on the screen, till termination.