# turtle graphics: How do I implement a pause function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to use python 3 turtle graphics to do something like presentation software: draw something, pause for a keystroke so the presenter can explain, then draw the next thing.

Here is one solution I've tried (that doesn't work):

```
import turtle
import time

paused = False

def unpause():
    print("unpause() called")
    global paused
    paused = False

def pause():
    global paused
    paused = True
    while paused:
        time.sleep(0.1)


t = turtle.Turtle()

# set up listener
t.screen.listen()
t.screen.onkeypress(unpause)

# draw something
t.hideturtle()
t.pensize(5)
t.speed(1)
t.pu()
t.goto(-300,-300)
t.pd()
t.goto(-300, 300)

# pause until key is pressed
pause()

# draw some more
t.pu()
t.goto(300,-300)
t.pd()
t.goto(300, 300)

t.screen.mainloop()
```

The problem is that the sleep call loop totally blocks the keypress from being detected, even when I use a while loop of very short (100ms) sleeps.

If I hit a key while the first line is drawing, I see "unpause() called" in my console, so I know that the key binding is active.

Why doesn't the keypress get detected? I don't know about the internals, but I thought that the keystroke would be recorded in a buffer somewhere, and during the break between sleep calls, the listener would read the buffer and unset the `paused` global variable. This is not happening.

Is there some other way I could implement this?

This is on a Debian Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

Turtle graphics is based on `tkinter`, which is an event-driven GUI framework, so you can't do things like you would in a regular procedurally-driven program — see @Bryan Oakley's answer to the question [Tkinter — executing functions over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342757/tkinter-executing-functions-over-time) for a more detailed explanation (although the `turtle` module hides most of these details). Anyway, this fact means you shouldn't call `time.sleep()` in an tight loop like that because everything has to happen without interfering with running of the `mainloop()`.

The "trick" to avoid calling `time.sleep()` is to schedule periodic checks of the global variable using the `turtle.ontimer()` function — so your program will work if the first part of it is changed as shown below:

```
import turtle

paused = False

def unpause():
    print("unpause() called")
    global paused
    paused = False

def pause():
    global paused
    paused = True
    pausing()  # Start watching for global to be changed.

def pausing():
    if paused:
        turtle.ontimer(pausing, 250)  # Check again after delay.
    # else quit checking.

t = turtle.Turtle()

# set up listener
t.screen.onkeypress(unpause)  # Reversed order of
t.screen.listen()             # these two statements.

# draw something
t.hideturtle()
t.pensize(5)
t.speed(1)
t.pu()
t.goto(-300,-300)
t.pd()
t.goto(-300, 300)

# pause until key is pressed
pause()

# draw some more
t.pu()
t.goto(300,-300)
t.pd()
t.goto(300, 300)

t.screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: the program just stops if I press any key, it does work for you?

Comment: Sorry, this code doesn't work for me. If I don't press any key, the second line will still get drawn.

I thought a solution could use `ontimer` in some way, but it appears that it simply ensures that the function is called when the timer's time is up: it doesn't stop the execution of the main program code.

I tested this by adding this function and calling it before drawing the first line:
`def disrupt():
    global t
    t.goto(t.ycor() - 10, t.xcor() + 10)
    turtle.ontimer(disrupt, 500)`
The line drawing is interrupted in the middle and an interesting pattern is drawn.

Comment: Bah, StackOverflow will only let me edit my comments for five minutes. I hope the newlines in my posted python function can be inferred.

Comment: You can't put newlines in comments, so they're not a good place to post multiple lines of code. Anyway, the `250` millisecond delay may be too long, try making it shorter. Meanwhile, I'll see if I can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the ideas your suggestions have given me (thanks martineau and kederrac!) I was able to come up with a solution. It involves wrapping each of my drawing tasks in a function, then using a dispatch function that either waits for a keypress with an `ontimer` loop, or calls the next drawing function.

This proof-of-concept code uses entirely too many globals, but it shows the technique:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
paused = False
current_task = 0

def unpause():
    global paused
    paused = False

def turtle_setup():
    global t
    t.screen.onkeypress(unpause)
    t.screen.listen()
    t.hideturtle()
    t.pensize(5)
    t.speed(1)

def draw_task_finished():
    global paused, current_task, drawing_tasks
    current_task += 1
    paused = True
    if current_task < len(drawing_tasks):
        draw_task_after_keypress()

def draw_task_after_keypress():
    global paused, current_task
    if paused:
        turtle.ontimer(draw_task_after_keypress, 100)
    else:
        drawing_tasks[current_task]()

def draw_thing_one():
    global t
    t.pu()
    t.goto(-300,-300)
    t.pd()
    t.goto(-300, 300)
    draw_task_finished()

def draw_thing_two():
    global t
    t.pu()
    t.goto(300,-300)
    t.pd()
    t.goto(300, 300)
    draw_task_finished()

drawing_tasks = [draw_thing_one, draw_thing_two]

turtle_setup()
drawing_tasks[0]()

t.screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use turtle.done()`function.`
Just make a input() function, and if input is entered, the program will run.
I tried this with basic approach.