# How do I make a cooldown in Turtle?

Tags: python, time, python-turtle

I'm making a game using Turtle, and need a throwing mechanic with a cooldown. I've tried to use the time module, but trying to classify the variables as `int()` or `float()` doesn't work.

```
def throw(throwcdstart,throwcd):
  if throwcd >= 2:
    throwcdstart = int(time.time())
    print('Thrown!')    #this is put here as a placeholder

throwcd = int(time.time()) - throwcdstart #this part is in a while true at the bottom, by the way
```

I've tried searching on here and Google, but the only results I got were for discord.py.

Edit: I forgot to say that I did set the `throwcd` variable as 2 at the start of my code.

Edit 2: There are also other things happening, like moving and enemy AI. I've tried to use things like `time.sleep()`, but it stalls the entire game when I do. I haven't tried `math` yet, because it seems pretty complicated.

Comment: what's a cooldown?

Comment: @PaulH a cooldown is where you aren't able to use an ability of some sort for a specific amount of time

Comment: Does the game just "hang" for the duration of the cooldown, or are there other things happening? If freezing-up is OK, just call `time.sleep(delay_in_seconds)`.

Comment: There are other things happening like moving.

Comment: In that case you might be able to use the [`turtle.ontimer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer) function to do it without causing everything to freeze-up. There's an example of its use in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60919146/355230) to another question. (There currently isn't enough code in your question for me to be more specific.)

Answer (score 0):

quite cheekily formulated, because the question was asked very unclearly:

```
def throw(throwcdstart,throwcd):
  if throwcd >= 2:
    throwcdstart = int(time.time())
    mycooldown = 0.5 # seconds <==============
    time.sleep(mycooldown)
    print('Thrown!')    #this is put here as a placeholder

throwcd = int(time.time()) - throwcdstart #this part is in a while true at the bottom, by the way
```