# How to get outputs in same line on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as to
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('340x110')

def final():
   for i in field.get():
      answer = tk.Label(text= chr(ord(i)+2))
      answer.pack()

text = tk.Label(text="String Encrypt", font=(30))
text.place(x=100)

text2 = tk.Label(text="Enter The Word/Sentence: ")
field = tk.Entry(width='30')
text2.place(x=0, y=30)
field.place(x=150,y=33)

but = tk.Button(command=final, text="Encrypt")
but.place(x=140, y=60)

window.mainloop()
```

This is the code. Outputs are coming in new line for every iteration. How can we get in the same line??

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see for every character in `field.get()` you are creating a new label (with only one character at a time) and then `pack`ing that straight to the window.

You would want to perform all your encryption algorithm on the entire string first, and then add *one* new label with the whole string:

```py
def final():
    result = ''
    for i in field.get():
        result += chr(ord(i)+2)
    answer = tk.Label(text=result)
    answer.pack()
```