# How to update a variable in a running function from another file using tkinter?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, input, global-variables

I have a working program for sorting some screws using computer vision. Now I want to make a user-interface using tkinter. I am trying to keep the `tkinter` file and my program file separate, but I have problems with making my user inputs work.

As you see below i have a `input` function where the user can write `"run"` or `"not"` in the console to make the program start:

```
#This is just a part of my function in the program file
while True:
    #Ask if user will run the program
    yesOrNo = input('\nrun or not\n')
    if yesOrNo == 'run':
        break
    elif yesOrNo == 'not':
        print('programmet stoppes')
        quit()
    else:
        print('use only "run" or "not"')
```

The trouble begins when i call my function in the tkinter file using a button. Because when I have started the function I don't know how to interact with the function. I have tried using an Entry() and then replace my `input()` with `entry.get()`, but this crashes my tkinter, because the `entry.get()`, doesn't wait for the user to write something and therefore keeps running the `while` loop.

So summed up I just want something that acts like the `input()` and waits for the user to click enter or a button and then my function has to get this value while running (therefore I can't put the value as an parameter in the function).
I want the input field to be inside my tkinter `root` and therefore I don't want to use `tkinter.simpledialog.askstring()`.

I am not good at global variables, but is that a way to go? Like making a global variable inside my tkinter file which somehow can be read by my function (from the other file) while running. And then changing the value of the variable with a button or so.

Comment: tkinter requires doing event-driven programming — so there's no "waiting for input". See [Introduction to GUI programming with `tkinter`](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html).

Comment: Also see @Bryan Oakley's answer to the question [Tkinter — executing functions over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342757/tkinter-executing-functions-over-time).

Comment: Thanks, that helped to understand tkinter a little better.
Would you recommend, that i maybe split up my program in more functions. Like each time i have a user input?

Comment: You're still thinking procedurally. While a number of tkinter widgets support an optional user-supplied "callback" function that will get called when certain things happen — like whenever a `Button` is clicked, `Entry` widgets don't. However you can arrange for one of your own functions to be called when certain things occur, such as when character is inserted or deleted from one — this is known as "validation". Describing how to do it is too complicated to put into a comment.

Comment: Here's a little [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry-validation.html) to get you started, the topic is probably covered in many tkinter tutorials, and of course there's a number of questions about here on SO as well.

Comment: That's a great document:)
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: As you said, you can use an `Entry` or `Radiobutton` to get the user input on `run` or `not`.  Then you can pass it as an argument to your program file instead of using `input()`.