# tkinter: How to get a subclass of Label to show on screen?

Tags: python, tkinter, subclass

I'm trying to do something with classes in Python (I come from a procedural languages background).  Trying to create a version of tkinter's `Label` widget supporting a couple of new methods to manipulate the text of the label.

My problem is that I can't get the label to actually be visible on the screen.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

DEFAULT_BG = '#f0f0f0'


class cngMsg(Label):
    """Message Display label"""
    def __init__(self, parent, w, h):
        """Init the Message Label"""
        self.parent = parent
        Label.__init__(self, parent)
        self.msgText = "Hello World"
        self.msgLabel = Label(parent, text=self.msgText)
        self.msgLabel.config(height=h, width=w, bg=DEFAULT_BG)

    def clear(self):
        self.msgText = ""
        print(len(self.msgText))
        self.msgLabel.config(text=self.msgText)

    def newMessage(self, message):
        print("about to display <" + message + ">")
        self.msgText = message
        print(len(self.msgText))
        self.msgLabel.config(text=self.msgText)

    def show(self, message, sameLine=None):
        if (not sameLine) and len(self.msgText) > 0:
            self.msgText += '/n'
        print("about to show: <" + message + ">")
        self.msgText = self.msgText + message
        print(len(self.msgText))
        self.msgLabel.config(text=self.msgText)


#Root Stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = Tk()
    app.title("Message Test")

    # this is the start of the application
    print("initialise the Message Test")

    gMsg = cngMsg(app, 60, 20)
    gMsg.pack()
    gMsg.newMessage("new message")
    gMsg.show("this is a test")
    gMsg.show("second test")

    app.mainloop()
```

The debug print messages appear on the console but the application window doesn't display the Label.

Comment: Each `cngMsg` is a Label that contains no text (or any other attributes, for that matter).  Instead, it *contains* another Label with actual text, but you never call `.pack()` on that Label to make it visible.  Basically, every reference to `self.msgLabel` should simply be `self`; there's no point in making your object a subclass of Label otherwise.

Comment: thanks to Bryan Oakley and martineau for speedy and clear answers.  I can see what I did wrong now thanks.
Aslo appreciate the references for further reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUI programming requires using a non-procedural paradigm since they are user-input driven. The question [Tkinter — executing functions over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342757/tkinter-executing-functions-over-time) discusses this and has some sample code.

Personally I have often found it useful when creating GUI apps to think of them as FSMs ([Finite State Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)) in which user inputs cause them to change their state.

Here's how to do something similar to what I think you were trying to in your sample code which is based on the @Bryan Oakley's answer to the linked question (updated to Python 3). It also shows the proper way to subclass `tkinter` classes. In addition it mostly follows the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guideline, which I *strongly* suggest your read and start following.

```
from tkinter import *

DEFAULT_BG = '#f0f0f0'
DEFAULT_MSG_TEXT = "Hello World"
DELAY = 1000  # Milliseconds.


class CngMsg(Label):
    """Message Display label"""
    def __init__(self, parent, w, h):
        # Intialize with default text and background color.
        super().__init__(parent, text=DEFAULT_MSG_TEXT, height=h, width=w, bg=DEFAULT_BG)

    def clear(self):
        self.config(text='')

    def newMessage(self, message):
        self.config(text=message)

    def show(self, message, same_line=False):
        text = self.cget('text')  # Get value of current option.
        if not same_line and text:
            text += '\n'
        text += message
        self.config(text=text)


class MyApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.test_msg = CngMsg(self.frame, 60, 20)
        self.test_msg.pack()

        self.state = 0
        self.do_test()

    def do_test(self):
        if self.state == 0:
            self.test_msg.newMessage("start message")
            self.state = 1
        elif self.state == 1:
            self.test_msg.show("this is a test")
            self.state = 2
        elif self.state == 2:
            self.test_msg.show("second test")
            self.state = 3
        elif self.state == 3:
            self.test_msg.clear()
            self.test_msg.show("TEST COMPLETED")
            self.state = -1  # Enter final state.
        elif self.state != -1:
            self.quit()  # Stop mainloop.
            raise RuntimeError("Unknown state encountered")

        if self.state != -1: # Not final state?
            self.after(DELAY, self.do_test)  # Schedule another call.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = MyApp()
    root.title("Message Test")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @matrineau - should there be a test around the `self.after(DELAY, self.do_test)` once the `self.state` reaches -1?

Answer (score 0):

Your `cngMsg` class is creating *two* labels. The first is the instance of that class itself. The second is created when you do `self.msgLabel = Label(parent, text=self.msgText)`. This second label is a child of the `cngMsg` label. Since you do not call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on that second label it will not appear anywhere.

In your `newMessage` method you are updating the text in the invisible label instead of the actual label.

You don't need this second label, and in `newMessage` you should configure itself like this:

```
def newMessage(self, message):
    self.msgText = msgText
    self.configure(text=self.msgText)
```

Similarly, `show` and `clear` should be defined in a similar way:

```
def clear(self):
    self.msgText = ""
    self.config(text=self.msgText)

def show(self, message, sameLine=None):
    if (not sameLine) and len(self.msgText) > 0:
        self.msgText += '/n'
    self.msgText = self.msgText + message
    self.config(text=self.msgText)
```