# tkinter dynamic Checkbutton pause/return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am having data in a text file.

```
AAA
BBB
CCC

111
222
333

!!!
@@@
###

XXX
YYY
ZZZ
```

No issue to read the file and able to assigned dict. Dict consist of key and pair list. One of the random keys selected and from the associated list a random line will pick up as a question. Associated question with the label.

The remaining element became the answers. Tried to set up a dynamic checkbox but was unable to pause the execution. For now, the idea is to get value via `Checkbutton`s and if it's part of the same pair, it should move to the next iteration.

I tried few things but was unable to handle return value. Not my method is correct. Should I use cmd button instead of waiting for `Checkbutton` clicks?

[image]

Here is my revised code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import random

window = Tk()

def quiz():
        chkValue = IntVar() 
        QL = Label(window,text = (Q), bg = "Blue").pack()
        for x in range(len(cpll[key])):
            chkValue[x] =  Variable()
            print(cpll[key][x])
            QA[x] = Checkbutton(window,text = cpll[key][x],var=chkValue[x], command=nextq).pack()[x],var=chkValue, command=nextq).pack()

def nextq():
        pass
# Using readlines()
file1 = open('cpll.txt', 'r')
lines = file1.readlines()
cpll ={}
count = 0
idx = 0

for line in lines:
    if line == "\n":
        idx +=1
        count += 1
    else:
        cpll.setdefault(idx,[]).append(line.strip())
        count += 1

for key, values in cpll.items():
    print(key)
    
    if(isinstance(values, list)):
        for value in values:
            print(value)
            
    else:
        print(value)

for value in cpll.values():
    print(value)
    
    
key_list = list(cpll)

random.shuffle(key_list)

d2 = {} 


for key in key_list:

        d2[key] = cpll[key]
        Q = random.choice(cpll[key])
        cpll[key].remove(Q)        

quiz()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter GUI programs don't execute [imperatively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) the way you're probably used to programming. They are [event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) — a completely different programming paradigm. See the answer to [Tkinter — executing functions over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342757/tkinter-executing-functions-over-time) for more information.

Comment: Also note that `Checkbutton`s don't pause or `return` values.

Answer (score 1):

Checkbuttons and other GUI widgets are not synchronous. You can't really wait for something to happen, but you can always check a value. GUIs are event-driven. So you can always use a change of widget state to trigger an action.

The Checkbutton widget has a `variable` option, which allows you to link that Checkbutton widget to a tkinter `IntVar()` integer variable. Then THAT `IntVar` can be traced to trigger a callback action whenever the `IntVar` is read from or written to. Once the Checkbutton widget is linked to the `IntVar`, changing the value of the IntVar will update the visual appearance of the Checkbutton, and clicking on the Checkbutton will update the value of the `IntVar`, triggering any callback function.

Here's an excerpt on the Checkbutton `variable` option from https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/checkbutton.html:

> The control variable that tracks the current state of the checkbutton;
> see Section 52, “Control variables: the values behind the widgets”.
> Normally this variable is an IntVar, and 0 means cleared and 1 means
> set, but see the offvalue and onvalue options above.

For more on `IntVar()`, check out https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/control-variables.html